# Cannot configure OpenDNS on iPad

Tags: dns, ipad, ios

The instructions on [Internet Safety Project](http://www.internetsafetyproject.org/wiki/setting-opendns-ios-ipod-ipad-wifi-only) seem simple enough, but, according to all the OpenDNS tests, websites are not working.

I am using a Wi-Fi iPad2 with iOS 7.

Comment: have you tried with both wifi and cellular?

Answer (score 2):

That site has the wrong IP addresses for the OpenDNS servers listed. Instead of 208.67.222.123 and 208.67.220.123 enter the correct addresses:

208.67.222.222 and 208.67.220.220

Source: [opendns.com](http://www.opendns.com)